# how to add flask-oauthlib to the cookiecutter-flask

Tags: python, oauth, flask, linkedin-api

I am learning flask by building my own app, based on [cookiecutter-flask template](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask) and I wont to add LinkidIn auth there. Right now I am using [Flask-User](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User) as login manager.

The problem is that I can't init this flask-oauth object as extension like here - [github](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/app.py#L39), because in my case it says, that oauth doesn't have init_app method

```
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth
oauth = OAuth()
oauth.init_app(app)
```

and I also can't understand, where should I put [linkedin config](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/example/linkedin.py#L10) object? Is it possible to use this extension with flask app factiry structure? or should I switch to the [Flask-Rauth](https://github.com/joelverhagen/flask-rauth)? (but it will introduce additional problems)

Answer (score 0):

just pass the `app` object to `OAuth`. something like this:

```
oauth = OAuth(app)
```

**UPDATE:** however I prefer to use flask-oauth instead